# "No such file or directory:" while parsing XML

Tags: python

I have a code to parse a xml as shown below

```
if(args.xml):
    filestring = global_defs.getDrive() + args.xml
    myFile=open(filestring)
    retval=ParseXml(myFile)
    myFile.close()
    print retval
```

I am giving correct path to my xml file. It doesn't seem to recognize it.

```
C:\app\Tools\exam\Python25>python tu_parser.py -xml \users\z234941\t\template_imagetool.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tu_parser.py", line 104, in <module>
    myFile=open(filestring)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\users\\z234941\\t\\template_imagetool.xml'
```

Anyone see where i am going wrong?

Comment: The system cannot open a file at the given location. Maybe give an absolute path?

Comment: Can you somehow prove to us that the path is correct?  What's the output of `dir` with the same path name parameter?  What about with/without a drive letter?

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
C:\app\Tools\exam\Python25>python tu_parser.py -xml "C:\\users\z234941\t\template_imagetool.xml"
```